# Generalization of Giuga's conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, primality-test

Can you give a counterexample for the following conjecture :

> For $m \ge 1$ and $n>2$ , $n$ is a prime iff
>
> $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n^m-1} k^{n^m-1} \equiv (n-1) \cdot n^{m-1} \pmod{n^m} $$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdiTEKwzAQBHuD_3C4OgkZI1KKK1PmC4I4dkCYWxlL_n_kQJpUOzM7Wbqjrgfh1LmN0hPLT0B26jsVHyA3H_ouvfmRFy6n8ibeIero3Rb5C8ZcwYgwmlhEvqLbj4TKoIFSoSa6Dn_xlXXPJdV2mPABRI8rWA==&lang=gp) .

P.S.

For $m=1$ we have [Giuga's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture) .

Comment: Even if this test is correct, there's no significant value over simply testing the divisibility of $n$ with all numbers smaller than $n$. There are plenty of prime formulas, but their computation complexity is not significantly lower than brute-force. For example, consider: $F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}\left\lceil\frac{{n}\bmod{k}}{n}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{n}\right\rceil}{n}\right\rfloor$. If $F_n=0$ then $n$ is not prime, if $F_n=1$ then $n$ is prime.

Comment: @barakmanos You are correct...this test has no practical value .

Comment: Isn't this just trying to use Fermat's little theorem while guarding against Fermat pseudoprimes?

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Essentially yes...